# Create a column based on value of another column using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please consider this data frame:

```
date         value      
-------------------
20201001      -100
20200202      200
20200303       0
...
```

I want to hav1e another very simple column: "Status"

**if Value < 0 Then "Status" = -1**

**if Value > 0 Then "Status" = 1**

**if Value = 0 Then "Status" = 0**

I wrote this code:

```
data['Status'] = (data['Value'] / math.fabs(data['Value'])) if data['Value'] != 0 else 0
```

but I got this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How to create this column without `For` loop. Thanks

**Edit 1)** I wrote the code this way but I got same error:

```
data['Status'] = (data['Value'] / math.fabs(data['Value'])) if data[data['Value'] != 0] else 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html):

```
data['Status'] = np.sign(data['Value'])
```

If only integers use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
data['Status'] = data['Value'].clip(lower=-1, upper=1)
```

Your solution working with list comprehension:

```
data['Status'] = [x / math.fabs(x) if x != 0 else 0 for x in data['Value']]
print (data)
       date  value  Status
0  20201001   -100    -1.0
1  20200202    200     1.0
2  20200303      0     0.0
```

**Performance**:

```
#300k rows
data = pd.concat([data] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [72]: %timeit data['Status'] = np.sign(data['Value'])
3.2 ms ± 57.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [73]: %timeit data['Status'] = data['Value'].clip(lower=-1, upper=1)
5.99 ms ± 49.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [74]: %timeit data['Status'] = [x / math.fabs(x) if x != 0 else 0 for x in data['Value']]
144 ms ± 483 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way without `numpy`?

Comment: @Arian - Then is possible use `clip`

Comment: thanks it works. But I want to know What's wrong with my code? Why I can't write condition that way? Thanks

Comment: @Arian - If need performance with multiple `if-else` best is use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), but for `-1,0,1` is best `np.sign` here

Comment: Honestly, I wanted to know what is wrong with my code that gives an error?

Comment: To debug your code, dismantle it and put it back together one command at a time.